# SQL select skip n values every n values

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a problem and no idea how to solve it. So, a user selects how many values he wants, then I check how many values can be returned (limited by some WHERE properties). Lets say there are 15 values and the user only wants 10.

So I want 2 out of 3 values in this example, how can I create a select that skips every third value?
The solution should also work with something like 5 out of 8 values.

I already searched through all solutions, mostly working with modulus and row_number or id. And while I could manually build some selects to work for certain scenarios, I lack the knowledge to make something that works just by dynamically changing some values, depending on the selected numbers.

All help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

My reasoning for skipping entries, instead of selecting the first / skipping the first / randomizing and then skipping:

The entries are actually positions, skipping entries is there to make the path rougher, I would prefer to do it directly in the Database to use the servers power, instead of doing it on the User machine, filtering out possibly hundreds of thousands of entries

Comment: Why not just show the first 10 values, like everybody else does?

Comment: simply add a ROW_NUMBER and and take all mod 3 but you need a SORTING column which determines which 2 out of 3 should be selected

Comment: Instead of skipping rows, you could consider `order by random()  limit n`

Comment: The rows are actually position data points, so I want to skip some points inbetween to make the path rougher. I still want the first and last point, that's why I can't just select the first 10. @SadlyFullStack

Comment: @nbk This would only select 5 points for me (3, 6, 9, 12, 15), not 10

Comment: The logic you need must be specific but the concept i told you works, so adapt it

Comment: To be honest I don't see how to quite reach the goal with modulus. While yes, I could do something like **skip every third entry**, its just not scalable. I also wrote the comment under an answer, but lets say I have 40 values and want 3 in 5. This would result in 2 more values than I want, as I would skip every 4th and 5th value, but 20 and 40 share the modulu This would only get worse as the numbers rise. Or am I missing something? @nbk

Comment: I am just dumb I think @nbk thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to skip every third row. You can easily customize it.

```
select *
from
(
select *
       ,row_number() over(order by col1) as rn
from t
) t
where rn%3 != 0
```

| col1 | rn |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 |
| 20 | 2 |
| 40 | 4 |
| 50 | 5 |
| 70 | 7 |
| 80 | 8 |
| 100 | 10 |
| 110 | 11 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/v3KozvOi)

Comment: First of all thank you, this would solve the first example I gave, I don't think it's quite scalable. Lets say the numbers are 3 out of 5. I would adapt it to `WHERE rn%4 != 0 AND rn%5 != 0` with lets say 40 values, this would result in 2 more values than I want, as 20 and 40 share the modulu. This would only get worse as the numbers rise. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Wouldn't you want 20 and 40 to filtered out? Check out this example: https://dbfiddle.uk/gI2pZAkf

Comment: Huh, my logic must be flawed, as I adapted the fiddle to my example and it worked. But to answer you, yes I would want 20 and 40 skipped. What I though was "Well, I am missing 2 removals, because %4 already removed 20 and 40 and now %5 can't". I still get my 24 / 40 (3 / 5) values, so I must be missing something, thank you very much, I will checkmark your answer @DannySlor (adapted Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/WBsSF5yN )